# Performance tuning OLTP query

Tags: performance, oracle-11g, database-tuning

I have the following SQLs executed millions of times a day, a single execution isn't an issue but executing million times is causing some performance issues..Thanks in advance for your help!

NOTE: data can change in any of the tables any time during the day..can't reduce number of executions and this is Oracle 11g env.

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
    INTO v_cnt
  FROM t1 cpr, t2 brl
 WHERE cpr.cp_id = :1
     AND cpr.brl_id = brl.brl_id
     AND brl.ranking > 0
     AND cpr.security_enabled_ind='Y'
     AND cpr.brl_id NOT IN (
                   SELECT rpr.brl_id
                     FROM t3 rpr, t4 ppr, t5 plcy
                    WHERE rpr.ppr_id = ppr.ppr_id
                      AND ppr.plcy_id = plcy.plcy_id
                      AND plcy.db_object_name = :2);
IF v_cnt = 0
THEN

SELECT where_clause
  FROM
    (SELECT where_clause
       FROM t4 ppr_o
     WHERE ppr_o.ppr_id IN (
                    SELECT ppr.ppr_id
                      FROM t1 cpr,
                           t3 rpr,
                           t4 ppr,
                           t5 plcy
                     WHERE cpr.cp_id = :1 
                        AND cpr.brl_id = rpr.brl_id
                        AND rpr.ppr_id = ppr.ppr_id
                        AND ppr.plcy_id = plcy.plcy_id
                        AND cpr.security_enabled_ind='Y'
                        AND plcy.db_object_name = :2
                        AND plcy.statement_type = :3)
    ORDER BY NVL (ppr_o.ranking, 0) DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
END IF;
```

Number of records

- t1 -> 205101
- t2 -> 42
- t3 -> 142
- t4 -> 57
- t5 -> 13

Comment: There are 86,400 seconds in the day. You are running this 12 times a second at least 24/7?

Comment: We have lot of users and there are cases where 300 users simultaneously executing these sqls..

Comment: What percentage of executions use the same bind values?

Comment: WHAT performance issues? I/O, contention, CPU? Look at the query plan and at AWR so you know what to tune.

Comment: can you show us the execution plan for both queries?

Comment: @Leigh Riffel..we dont have that level of information currently since we dont log this query's execution.

Comment: @Sree So then log it or trace it.  This is important information along with the other things listed that will help determine the best course of action.

Answer (score 1):

I would first consider trying to combine the two queries into one. If the second query could be refactored to return `null` in the case where the first query returned zero would you be able to work with that?

For example,

testbed:

```
create table t1( cp_id integer, 
                 brl_id integer, 
                 security_enabled_ind char(1) );
create table t2( brl_id integer, 
                 ranking number );
create table t3( ppr_id integer,
                 brl_id integer );
create table t4( ppr_id integer, 
                 plcy_id integer, 
                 where_clause varchar(1000), 
                 ranking number );
create table t5( plcy_id integer, 
                 db_object_name varchar(100), 
                 statement_type integer );
```

refactored query:

```
with w as ( select rpr.brl_id, ppr_id, plcy.statement_type
            from t3 rpr join t4 ppr using(ppr_id) join t5 plcy using(plcy_id)
            where plcy.db_object_name=:2 )
select where_clause
from( select where_clause
      from t4 ppr_o
      where not exists ( select *
                         from t1 cpr join t2 brl using(brl_id)
                         where cpr.cp_id = 1 and brl.ranking > 0
                               and cpr.security_enabled_ind='Y'
                               and brl_id not in (select brl_id from w) )
            and ppr_o.ppr_id in ( select ppr_id
                                  from t1 cpr join w using(brl_id)
                                  where cpr.cp_id=:1
                                        and cpr.security_enabled_ind='Y'
                                        and w.statement_type=:3 )
    order by ppr_o.ranking desc nulls last )
where rownum=1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the query..we are actually trying to avoid querying transaction tables million times, looking for snapshots kind of approach or caching tables or any other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple runs with the same parameters occur between changes in the data you could consider a [Server Results Cache](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/memory.htm#PFGRF982).  It will use some memory, but when it can use the cache it should decrease the performance hit.